# iOS: How can I change the orientation of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, orientation, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController` that I load when a user turns their iPad so as to put it into landscape orientation. The problem I’m having is that my `UICollectionViewCell`s are still loading as if it were in portrait orientation. I set the `UICollectionViewController` to landscape inside Interface Builder, and I’m using a custom cell class that I’ve called `CollectionViewCell`. Each cell contains just an image and a label.

Is there something that I should be doing either in Interface Builder or in my code? I tried using `CGAffineTransformationMakeRotation`, but that was no help. If anyone else has encountered this before, I would be extremely grateful! Thanks very much!

Here’s a bit of the code for reference:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return listArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{      
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"devices" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.statusImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    cell.name.text=@"HEY !!!!!";
    return cell;
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(320, 420);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else has had this problem, here is how I solved it.

I was initially not allowing autorotation, and instead was just registering for `orientationChanged` notifications using `NSNotificationCenter`. This worked great except that it was preventing my second view from realizing that it needed to load in landscape mode.

So instead of that, I’ve created a class for the `tabBar` that my main view is embedded in, and I return `NO` for the `shouldAutoRotate` method in that class and in every other view except for the one which I want to load in landscape mode. I’m still using the `orientationChanged` notifications in my main view’S controller, since it is embedded in the `tabBar`. But I’m just using autorotation when returning to the main view.

If anyone has any questions, let me know. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am using a custom UICollectionView with dynamic heights in every cell. But When i rotate, my cell are not changing width via columnWidthForCollectionView method and number of columns via maximumNumberOfColumnsForCollectionView method. I'm calculation my column width dynamically. via -(CGFloat)getCollumnWidth
{
    CGFloat width = (self.view.frame.size.width-(kCollectionCellBorderRight*3))/2;
    return width;
}
This is happening in both iPhone and iPad.